# How to create a function that does not take inputs. For example roll a fair dice for 10 times and take the sum?

Tags: r

I am new to R and this is my thoughts.

I did:

`summm<- function(z){ x<- sample(6,12,replace = TRUE) z<- sum(x) }`

I name this function as summm.
But when I type summm, I didn't get any result back.

How can I get some results?

Thank you for your time and for your help!

Comment: You don't need to put anything inside the `function()` parens. But you always need parens when calling a function.

Answer (score 2):

You perform a function call with `<function_name>(<arguments>)`. If your function does not require input, define it with no formal arguments:

```
summm <- function() {
  sum(sample(6, 12, replace = TRUE))
}

> summm()
[1] 46
```

As for "not getting return back": in your example, the last operation your function performs is assignment. This is because assignment returns an invisible value, and functions return the last evaluated expression. So the function returns an invisible value, which exists, but doesn't print to the console.

There is never any reason to perform assignment as the last operation in a function since the assignment is only valid within the scope of the function call.